# How to use the return value of the first task in the second task's group for loop?

Tags: python, celery, chain

I have two celery tasks:

```
@app.task
def task1(a, b, c, d):
    # do some stuff and find the return value
    return r

@app.task
def task2(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
   # do some other stuff
```

I want to first execute task1 and then execute a group of task2 in parallel:

```
c = chain(task1.s(a, b, c, d), group(task2.si(a, b, c, e, i, j) for i, j in enumerate(range(e))))
```

But, the "e" argument above is the return value of the task1, which is passed to task2 and is used in the for loop. How could that be implemented using Celery?

Answer (score 0):

You may specify a base for your first task and have it call the second task with the retVal of the first. You can do this in the on_success method of your base.

```
import Task from Celery

def setVal():
    return 1, 2, 3

class FollowUp(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, *args, **kwargs):

        for i, j in enumerate(range(retval)):
            task2.si(a, b, c, retval, i, j) # a, b, c should be set before here
        # Use a task set here if you need to collectively verify the status of your tasks
        # http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.task.sets.html


@app.task(base=FollowUpTask)
def add(*args):
    return 3


@app.task
def task2(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
    pass
```